# Install graphical interface on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, graphical-user-interface

I need to install a GUI on an Ubuntu Server instance and another Debian base server (no GUI ofcourse).

I just need the minimum, a gnome-terminal or similar and a browser. Don't want to install the whole gnome package.

apt-get install ubuntu-desktop is not a valid solution as it change the kernel to generic.

Thanks!!

PD: Any x-Forwarding manual to do this??. I'm using a Windows client :(

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to achieve by installing GUI on server, so that we can help you?

Comment: I need a browser to access via Web to my wifi access points that are in a private network only accesible via this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. All you really need to do is to be able to proxy web traffic through the box so you can gain access to the config pages of your APs.

SSH tunneling is perfect for this.

From your workstation:

```
$ ssh user@host.example.com -D8888
```

This will set up a SOCKS-compatible web proxy. Then configure your workstation's browser to use localhost:8888 as a SOCKS proxy. After doing this, all web traffic will be tunneled through the host.example.com and you should be able to access your APs.

Answer (score 0):

For Desktop environment you can try for [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/)

For web browser, you can try for [Dillo](http://www.dillo.org/)